# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error

Tags: mysql, oracle, select, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

Keep getting this error when everything from my select is in my group by statement as far as I can see

```
SELECT DISTINCT Case_Client_ID, Case_Client_Forename, Case_Client_Surname, SUM(Hours_Spent*Rate_Price_Per_Hour) AS
Money_Paid
FROM Case_Client, Legal_Case, Note, Rate
WHERE Case_Client.Case_Client_ID = Legal_Case.FK_Case_Client_ID
AND Legal_Case.Legal_Case_ID = Note.FK_Legal_Case_ID
AND Rate.Rate_ID = Note.FK_Rate_ID
GROUP BY Case_Client_ID, Case_Client_Forename, Case_Client_Surname
HAVING ROWNUM<=(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Case_Client)/4
ORDER BY Money_Paid DESC;
```

Comment: what is this ROWNUM?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy `Rownum` is a pseudo-column that gives the number/count of the row in Oracle Database. It only increments for rows included in the result, and is ordered arbitrarily, unless after an ordered inline view.

Comment: but there is no Rownum in mysql, so your query will not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Oracle and not MySQL, both are tagged.

The problem is `rownum` in the `having` clause. `Rownum` will have multiple values for a single group.

I am unclear what you are attempting to do, so I don't have a fix to suggest.